# How to rationalise multiple projects where everything is identical apart from one external source file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, build, visual-studio-2019

We use a protocol language where a special compiler generates a .c file containing global variables based on the protocol definition.

We interface with about 20 of these systems and each has a different protocol definition but the structure of the .c file is identical, just the values of variables differ. It is basically a compile-time configuration file.

So we currently have 20 VS projects each with one source code file plus the generated .c file. Each project's own source file is identical apart from the project name, basic boiler-plate code. It means if we want to make a change, we have to do it in 20 places.

We cannot change the generated .c file approach, but is there any way we could have some sort of project template, and the 20 individual projects are built from this? Does Visual Studio (2019) provide any tools along these lines?

Comment: You could add all those different C files to one project, then define 20 configurations and exclude all but one from build in each config. Maybe also define per-config intermediate and output directories/filenames. This would get multiplied by the x86/x64 and debug/release combinations, but it would still be a one time setup.

Comment: Clever solution @dxiv